# Clearing a field of a react-hook-form using mui and yup

Tags: reactjs, spring-mvc, material-ui, react-hook-form

I need a function to clear a list fields of a form, but not reset() since it should display as changed.

I have three Options, setting **null**, **undefined** or **''**.

- **null**

  - yup claims that fields are non nullable, even when they are not required. And i dont want to add .nullable() to all fields.
- **undefined**

  - the input fields are not cleared and still show the old value. I dont know if i can change that behaviour. Adding a custom Deserializer for each enum does not sound like a good solution to me.
- **''**

  - Spring complains that it cannot convert an empty string to an enum, instead of just setting null.

**Question**

Is there a simple solution for one of these three Problems, which can be applied globally, instead of touching multiple

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was setting

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.read-unknown-enum-values-as-null=true
```